# Calling constructor functions dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm looking to call a constructor function dynamically based on an value I have in an object.

Let's say I have an object:

```
var food = {

  pizzas:[
    {
      pizza: 'Pepperoni'
    },
    {
      pizza: 'Vegetarian'
    }
  ]

}
```

Now, let's say I have a couple of Constructor functions bound to a global object.

```
window.pizzaConstructors.Pepperoni = function(){
  // do something
}

window.pizzaConstructors.Vegetarian = function(){
  // do something else
}
```

What I want to be able to do is cycle through the `food.pizzas` array and call the corresponding constructor function based on the type of `pizza` of the current index.

So, if I have:

```
(for pizza in food.pizzas){
  var currentPizza = food.pizzas[pizza]

  new pizzaConstructors.currentPizza(); 
}
```

Any idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[]` syntax to access the constructors.

```
(for pizza in food.pizzas){
  var currentPizza = food.pizzas[pizza]

  new pizzaConstructors[currentPizza](); 
}
```

This `new pizzaConstructors.currentPizza()` means call the named `currentPizza` function.

This `new pizzaConstructors[currentPizza.pizza]()` means evaluate the `currentPizza`, get it's value, call the function with the named of the evaluated `currentPizza`.

```js
var food = {
  pizzas:[
    {
      pizza: 'Pepperoni'
    },
    {
      pizza: 'Vegetarian'
    }
  ]
};

const pizzaConstructors = {};

pizzaConstructors.Pepperoni = function(){};
pizzaConstructors.Vegetarian = function(){};

const arrOfObjects = [];

for (pizza in food.pizzas) {
  const currentPizza = food.pizzas[pizza].pizza;

  arrOfObjects.push(new pizzaConstructors[currentPizza]()); 
}

console.log(arrOfObjects);
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Perfect, thank you.